# How do I query my WordPress blog to list most recent posts on my Vue.js website?

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js

I'm trying to get my most recent posts from my website but am having trouble with calling the API correctly. What am I doing wrong?

I am using WordPress API version 1.1 and Vue.js version 2.0. I have Axios properly installed and all the necessary tools including Vue.js Devtools to see the results of a proper API call.

But, once I call the API it doesn't list any posts.

```
<template>
    <div>
        <div>
            <p>{{posts}}</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
import Axios from "axios"

    export default {
        name: 'Blog',
        mounted() {
            this.getPosts();
        },
        data() {
            return {
                postsURL: "https://public-api.wordpress.com/rest/v1.1/sites/ninjawebsitedesign.com/blog/posts/?number=2&pretty=true",
                posts: [],
                postsData: {
                    per_page: 20,
                    page: 1
                }
            }
        },
        methods: {
            getPosts() {
                Axios.get(this.postsUrl, { params: this.postsData })
                    .then((response) => {
                        this.posts = response.data
                    })
                    .catch((error) => {
                        console.log(error)
                    })
            }
        }
    }
</script>

<style scoped>
    ul li {
        color: black !important;
    }
</style>
```

Comment: Need some basic debugging details beyond *"doesn't work"* which tells us little of value. Is request being made, error etc? If made what does response lookl like?

Comment: Did you check if your request is giving any data back?

Answer (score 0):

you need to enable REST API on wordpress and use this url api : https://ninjawebsitedesign.com/wp-json/posts

Comment: Okay, but my WordPress site is stored on a folder. The main domain is a Vue.js app. How do I reference a site not stored on the main domain?

What is the URL designation?

The "/" seem to work to separate certain API functions so how do I indicate a "folder" like ninjawebsitedesign.com/blog as being the WordPress website I'm calling API's from?

Comment: so you dont have url API for your wordpress, did you have access to wordpress panel ?
you need two endpoint api.wordpress.com(with secure token) and vuejs.com
TUTO : https://snipcart.com/blog/wordpress-vue-headless

Comment: I finished it, thanks!

https://www.ninjawebsitedesign.com/Posts/